# cakephp no id passed to Form

Tags: cakephp

I have two forms, one to edit room details and the other to edit Extras. Within the forms I pull in a file upload and pass in the id. For some reason one requires a url and the id does not get passed in. Both have the same code. Can see why they are differnt.

**Room form**

```
            <div class="boxgrid grid_8">
            <?php echo $this->element('attachments',array('control'=>'upgrades','id'=>$this->data['AddOn']['id'],'att'=>$this->data['Attachment'])); ?>
            </div>
```

**Room upload**

Form->create('Room', array('type' => 'file'));?>

```
    <legend><?php __('Upload Room Images'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
?>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Attachment][0][model]" value="Room" id="Attachment0Model" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[Attachment][0][group]" value="attachment" id="Attachment0Group" />
<div class="input file required"><input type="file" name="data[Attachment][0][file]" class="" id="Attachment0File" /></div>


<div class="submit"><button>Upload</button></div>
<div>Upload files</div>
```

**Extras Form**

```
            <div class="boxgrid grid_8">
            <?php echo $this->element('attachments',array('control'=>'upgrades','id'=>$this->data['AddOn']['id'],'att'=>$this->data['Attachment'])); ?>
            </div>
```

**Extras Upload**

Form->create('Upgrade', array('type' => 'file','url'=>'/admin/upgrades/addfiles','id'=>'AddOnAdminAddfilesForm'));?>

```
    <legend><?php __('Upload Addon Images'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
?>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Attachment][0][model]" value="AddOn" id="Attachment0Model" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[Attachment][0][group]" value="attachment" id="Attachment0Group" />
<div class="input file required"><input type="file" name="data[Attachment][0][file]" class="" id="Attachment0File" /></div>


<div class="submit"><button>Upload</button></div>
<div>Upload files</div>
```

**Javascript on each form:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("div#uploader").resloader();
    $("div#uploader").load('<?=BASE_URL?>/admin/upgrades/addfiles/<?=$this->data['AddOn']['id']?>',null,function(){}).fadeIn();
```

Upgrades Contoller

```
            function admin_addfiles($id = null) {
            $this->layout = null;

                if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Add On', true));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'upgrades',  'action' => 'index'));
                }

                if (!empty($this->data)) {
                    $this->layout = null;
                    //if(empty($this->data['AddOn']['id'])){unset($this->data['AddOn']);}

                    // restructure data for uploader plugin // NEED TO GET RID OF THIS ? MOVE IT
                    $tmp_file = $this->data['Attachment'][0]['file'];
                    $tmp_file['extension'] =  array_reverse(explode('.', $tmp_file['name']));
                    $tmp_file['extension'] = $tmp_file['extension'][0];
                    $tmp_file['title'] = strtolower(substr($tmp_file['name'],0,(0-strlen('.'.$tmp_file['extension']))));
                    $this->data['Attachment'][0]['alternative'] = ucwords(str_replace('_',' ', $tmp_file['title']));

                    if ($this->AddOn->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'first'))) { 

                        $id = $this->AddOn->Attachment->getLastInsertID();
                        $att = $this->AddOn->Attachment->query("SELECT * from attachments WHERE id = ".$id);
                        $this->set('attachment',$att[0]['attachments']);

                    } else {
                        $tmp_file['name'] = 'INVALID FILE TYPE';
                    }


                    //debug($this->data);
                    $this->set('file', $tmp_file);
                    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'ajax');
                    $this->render('../elements/ajax');

                }

                if (empty($this->data)) {
                    $this->data = $this->AddOn->read(null, $id);
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the $this->data. Check how it is filled in your controller.

Both views are NOT the same, the main difference is in the create form.

> Form->create('Room', array('type' => 'file'));?>
>
> Form->create('Upgrade', array('type' => 'file','url'=>'/admin/upgrades/addfiles','id'=>'AddOnAdminAddfilesForm'));?>

As you can see, one has the first parameter 'Room' and the other one is 'Upgrade', this IS important since you call the id like this

> echo $this->Form->input('id');

Cake expects that for the first case you have something like, $this->data['Room']['id'] and the second one $this->data['Upgrade']['id']

If you pass from the controller your id variable like this

```
$this->set('id',$id);
```

then in the view you can do somthing like this

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('value'=>$id, 'type'=>'hidden'));
?>
```

Hope this solves your answer, if not, please post the $this->data value of each and the part of the controller where you assign $this->data

Comment: I have tried but still not wirking. I know that the .resloader loads the correct file and is passing the id. The problem seems to be that the form is not being created properly. Just to get it to load I had to put in the url. Which is something I did not have to do for the others.

Comment: Why would the upgrades form have to have ('Upgrade', array('type' => 'file','url'=>'/admin/upgrades/addfiles','id'=>'AddOnAdminAddfilesForm')) and the others dont to work? I have added the controller code above.

Comment: your form needs the url because it goes to a different place (maybe the admin area or something like that), the controller part seems to be wrong. You are expecting a parameter id, but none is send with the form...the url sent needs to be like http://localhost/admin/upgrades/addfiles/16 so it have an id, you are sending the id as post data so it will be as i told you before $this->data['Room']['id'] or $this->data['Upgrade']['id'] and you use id, also try not to use $this->model->query, use find

Comment: Is the id not sent to the controller by the ajax $("div#uploader").load('<?=BASE_URL?>/admin/upgrades/addfiles/<?=$this->data['AddOn']['id']?>',null,function(){}).fadeIn(); It works for loading the other forms? I have noticed thet the model is called add_on and the controller and views are called upgrades, would that cause this issue?

Comment: oh yes, i didn't see it. That's correct, you are sending it at that point. Make sure that $this->data['AddOn']['id'] exists, check the controller where this data is loaded (not received) to see if it's being sended correctly to the view. Maybe it has another path depending on the associations from the model, like $this->data[0]['AddOn']['id'], try doing a print_r or var_dump to $this->data or use cakephp debugkit (really usefull) [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit)

Comment: I have done a pr() in the starrt of the controller and the id is being passed as I thought. But when on this controller it is creating a new entry anod not updating why the other controller for rooms is working with the exact same code  function admin_addfiles($id = null) {
 $this->layout = null;
  pr($id);

Comment: if $id is correct, maybe the problem is here : $id = $this->AddOn->Attachment->getLastInsertID();
try printing before and after to see if this gives the correct result. (this line is equal to $id = $this->AddOn->Attachment->id), Also remeber, that cake autofill happens in te view, make sure that $this->data corresponds with the name of the form input you are trying to auto fill

Comment: Thanks for that. I now see that the id is getting passsed and then discovered that the view was the issue and that the database does get updated. There is so much data in there I must have missed it. However a there is still a problem, if an addon already has a image in the attachements table then it should update that. It is actualy creating another record so it has many images associated. It should be in no image for addon then new record, if already record, then update. I dont see where it is.

Comment: saveAll will only save data, won't update (at least i couldn't make it work), i use $this->RelatedModel->id =$RelatedModelId then savefield function, here is an [example](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data)

Comment: great, I think I will start another question on this as it is an interesting subject. I have read some material on this and none have addressed updating and creating a new record as needed. Thanks